Creating 2GP package version error: FlowDefinition entities not supported
When creating a 2GP package version, I get the following error.
These entities are not supported: [FlowDefinition]

I ran into this same error a long time ago, but I can't remember the details of how I resolved it. Forums seem to suggest adding to forceignore, but I have defined flow metadata in FlowDefinition that is part of the package. Here is the FlowDefinition xml (I only have one):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FlowDefinition xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <activeVersionNumber>1</activeVersionNumber>
</FlowDefinition>

I believe the issue the first time was that the versionNumber didn't match the flow version number, but I can't remember the details.
Has anyone else run into this before?

I believe you only want the flows and not the flow definitions in your package.

Just remove the FlowDefinition file from the package.
Only Flow Metadata Type(a.k.a .flow-meta.xml) is needed when you want to deliver a flow through a package.
